# how to encode api URL using base64 in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

how to encode URL using base64 in laravel?

I need something like this:

original URL: `http://localhost/dashboard/api/test/`

encode URL: `http://localhost/dashboard/YXBpL3Rlc3Qv`

Comment: Thanx @Ankuraggrwal

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing) you can do it like this:

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{code}', function($code){
     $url = base64_decode($code);
     //redirect according to $url ... for example "api/test/"
     return redirect( $url );
});
```

Comment: You can generate $url from the base64 depending on how you generated it in the first place ... you can make it dynamic by generating it from current user or from date ... be creative

Comment: If the new base64 URL is static (always the same) i don't see why you should change it ... it's bad practice

Answer (score 2):

I've found this piece of code which helped me, I'm just looking for something that removes "=" from base64 string so here :-

```
<?php
    function base64url_encode($data) {
      return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    }

    function base64url_decode($data) {
      return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
    }
?>
```

Example :-

```
dump(rtrim(strtr(base64_encode('Hello World'), '+/', '-_'), '='));
$encodedString = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode('Hello World'), '+/', '-_'), '=');
dd(base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($encodedString, '-_', '+/'), strlen($encodedString) % 4, '=')));
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Good solution. The `str_pad()` however is both incorrect and unnecessary here. A padding is never added because `% 4` is always < 4 and the passed string is most likely longer than 4 characters. Also `base64_decode()` does not case about the '=' padding at the end.